# Why does constructor function (with "return this") return window object?

Tags: javascript, this

I have a function

```
function Person(name){
this.name = name;
return this;
}
alert(Person("somename"));
```

This is returning [Object Window], how we can change this to [object object]? Is there any way we can change this function to get [object object] without changing signature.

Comment: You forgot `new`

Comment: Remove the `return this` line as well. It is not needed, as that is the implied behavior with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, when you call a function as in:

```
Person("somename")
```

The `this` pointer in that function call is set to either the global object or `undefined` (if running in strict mode).  That's what is happening in your statement:

```
alert(Person("somename"));
```

---

If, you want `Person()` to work as a constructor where a new `Person` object is created for you automatically, then you must include the `new` operator as in:

```
alert(new Person("somename"));
```

The `new` operator then creates a new object of that type and then calls the constructor with the `this` pointer set to that new object.  That is exactly what it is for.  Also, there is no need to do `return this` when using a constructor with `new` as that is done for you automatically.

---

You could make the form work you were using without using `new`, but then you'd have to create your own object in the `Person` function like this:

```
function Person(name){
    var p = {};      // create an empty object
    p.name = name;   // assign the name field
    return p;        // return the newly created object
}
```

There are some drawbacks to doing it this way, particularly in that `instanceof Person` won't work properly, so using the `new` operator is generally preferred.  I find that using `new` also makes the code more readable because it's more obvious when you are creating a new object and when you are just calling a function.